# Configuring HTTP pages and HTTPS pages with Spring Security

Tags: spring, ssl, spring-security

I have successfully setup an application using Spring Security. When users request the secured pages, Spring automatically redirects these users to a HTTPS page.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="true" >
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/my-account" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>

    <logout />
    <form-login login-page="/login" />
    <port-mappings>
        <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
        <port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
    </port-mappings>
</http>
```

But when the users navigate, the next other pages that does not have sensitive information are still using HTTPS. I would like these normal pages accessed using just HTTP.

Is any intelligent way to do that? All the other pages that I do not configured as HTTPS channel I would like to be accessed using just HTTP. I tried to use some wildcards but without success.

**Extra detail:**
HTTPS uses more server CPU. I have a lot of requests on some pages and I would like to avoid this extra cost.

Comment: Why not use HTTPS for the entire site? See FireSheep

Comment: I read that it uses more server CPU. I have a lot of requests on some pages and I would like to avoid this extra cost.

Answer (score 1):

Make your entire site HTTPS. Performance change is minimal these days and you won't screw over your users by exposing their session cookies over HTTP.

https://istlsfastyet.com/

Answer (score 0):

In Spring-Security, you can do this way -

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" once-per-request="true" >
<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/my-account" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" requires-channel="http"/>
```

All other url's besides "/login" and "/my-account" will be served over http.

In addition to this, you **must** set the secure flag for the cookie.
By setting the secure flag, the browser will prevent the transmission of a cookie over an unencrypted channel.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag

Comment: The last line does not override all the other configurations?

Comment: The last line does not override the previous intercept-url configurations. Spring Security does intercept-url pattern matching from top to bottom and for the first match found, it applies the "requires-channel" that is configured. So for the above lines, all the url patterns (besides "/login" and "/my-account") ,the channel will be HTTP.